# Почему-то возникает ошибка в ExampleAdapter именно на Android 5.1 и 6.0?

Tags: java, android

Почему-то возникает ошибка в ExampleAdapter именно на Android 5.1 и 6.0? Беблиотеку использую AndroidX. На Android выше 7.0 - все нормально.

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> implements Filterable {
private List<ExampleItem> exampleList;
private List<ExampleItem> exampleListFull;

class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView thumbnail;
    TextView textView1;


    ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        textView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view2);

    }
}

ExampleAdapter(List<ExampleItem> exampleList) {
    this.exampleList = exampleList;
    exampleListFull = new ArrayList<>(exampleList);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item,
            parent, false);
    return new ExampleViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ExampleItem currentItem = exampleList.get(position);

    holder.thumbnail.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource()); //тут чомусь помилка виникає на Android 5.1, а на інших нормально.
    holder.textView1.setText(currentItem.getText1());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return exampleList.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return exampleFilter;
}

private Filter exampleFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        List<ExampleItem> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            filteredList.addAll(exampleListFull);
        } else {
            String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            for (ExampleItem item : exampleListFull) {
                if (item.getText1().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                    filteredList.add(item);
                }
            }
        }

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        results.values = filteredList;

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        exampleList.clear();
        exampleList.addAll((List) results.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
}
```

ExampleItem

```
public class ExampleItem {
private int thumbnail;
private String text1;


public ExampleItem(int thumbnail, String text1) {
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    this.text1 = text1;

}

public int getImageResource() {
    return thumbnail;
}

public String getText1() {
    return text1;
 }
}
```

Код ошибки

```
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0800ab
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1266)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.loadDrawableFromDelegates(ResourceManagerInternal.java:252)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:139)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:132)
    at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:104)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:86)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:94)
    at ua.pl.akathist.ExampleAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ExampleAdapter.java:51)
    at ua.pl.akathist.ExampleAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ExampleAdapter.java:17)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:286)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:343)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:359)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:366)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:397)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: В логе четко написано, что вылет происходит на функции onBindViewHolder. Внутри нее нет обращений к ресурсам, значит проверять надо обращения к ресурсам в методе  currentItem.getImageResource(). Выложите код этой функции

Comment: Я выложил код ExampleItem,  ищу метод currentItem.getImageResource(). Давно писал код, пытаюсь вспомнить. Я только учусь.  Ошибка возникает когда начинаю прокручивать скролом.

Comment: Откуда берётся это значение - не в базе случаем оно хранится? При пересборке приложения id ресурсов могут измениться и стать невалидными.

Comment: Я разобрался, я сам допустил ошибку. Проблема была в том, что разные ImageView я назвал одним и тем же id. Прошу прощения. Спасибо woesss.

Comment: Стоит ли мне удалить свой вопрос со своей же ошибкой?

Comment: Моё мнение - вопрос без ответа мало-полезен, но маячит в поиске потесняя другие. Но с другой стороны проблема решена и это может кому-то пригодиться (и вопросы с ошибкой `Resources$NotFoundException` периодически появляются). Думаю лучшим вариантом будет если вы напишете ответ, чуть более подробный чем комментарий.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что разные ImageView я назвал одним и тем же id. А как обьяснил  woesss (спасибо огромное), при пересборке приложения id ресурсов могут измениться и становиться невалидными. Поэтому, я думаю, эмулятор на android 7.0 это пропускал, а с android ниже 7.0 показывали ошибку.

Comment: Вот теперь я засомневался в полезности ответа))) Если вы сохранили `id` ресурса в виде числа в префы, файл, базу, на сервере и т.п., а потом используете его в обновлённой версии приложения - тогда это проблема. Но если в каждом запуске приложения `id` получен через `R` - класс, то пересборка на это не влияет (если она, конечно, прошла без глюков). И по стеку у вас не найден ресурс картинки, а не `ImageView`. Может вы вставляли `id` `ImageView` вместо `id` картинки?

Comment: Я новичек, для меня это так все сложно. Я просто хочу сделать третье, последнее, приложение. Наверное так оно и есть как вы говорите.
Давайте я удалю свой глупый вопрос, что бы не сбивать с толку других людей? У меня этих глупых вопросов будет еще много, ведь осталось совсем немного до завершения моего третьего приложения. Потом я сяду за книги.